# Generating an invalid file name for testing purposes

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, unit-testing

I have a piece of code that I need to test. One of the test requires to add coverage where a `stream.Writable` is created giving a specified `output` file name.

I need to test the case where the `Writable` should fail, that it should emit the `error` event and the proper error handling function should execute, etc. etc.

Now, I thought I should only create some invalid file, using some weird name. But the task seems a bit harder than expected.

How can I voluntarily make this code snippet go into the `catch` block?

```
outputFile = String(outputFile);   // not exactly how this is really done, 
                                   // but the end result is the same

try {
  writer = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile, { flags: 'w' })
    .on('error', errorHandler)          // basically throws the error
    .on('close', closeHandler);         // function 100% tested
} catch (e) {
  // irrelevant code regarding this question, untested so far
}
```

Basically, what could be the value of `outputFile`?

#### ** Edit **

A screen cap of the temp test directory where weird names are created from that offending code.

[image]

Comment: without knowing much about node, I'd mock `fs.createWriteStream`. if fs is a global variable, then in your test, right before executing the function this snippet is from, do `_oldWritestream = fs.createWriteStream; fs.createWriteStream = function () { throw 'mock error' };` that will ensure you'll end up in the catch block no matter what outputFile you throw at it. After the test is run restore fs.createWriteStream and you should be good to go

Comment: Name of file cannot contain / ? * : ; { } \

Comment: @laggingreflex, that's funny, because I did try to create files like `"invalid*file?name"` and no error was thrown. Even `"invalid\\file"`.

Comment: Have you tried to actually write to the stream? Because that's probably when it'll throw the error.

Comment: @laggingreflex: actually, yes. Thus why I said "But the task seems a bit harder than expected.". It does create files like `invalid*file` and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:

try using a really long filename. ( seems like fs supports only upto 255-260 characters long)

ignore below part

---

my solution would be to have a common errorHandler, i.e the code would something like...

```
try{
        writer = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile, { flags: 'w' })
        .on('error',errorHandler)
        .on('close', closeHandler);
}catch(e){
    errorHandler(e);
}
```

Comment: The concept of "testing" code is not "Change the code to adapt the tests", but rather "Find solutions to test existing code". This is no good.

Comment: you need not modify the code in catch block, just take it out, put it inside ```var errorHandler = function(e){...}```

Comment: Read my last comment. I will not repeat myself.

Comment: cann't help it, if i am correct, createWriteStream is async, the other option would be to replace it with something that is synchronous...

Comment: That's the problem: you are not correct. Firstly, `createWriteStream` is async... just as JavaScript, and especially under V8, should be. Secondly, you keep suggesting changing the code while I specifically wrote that "I need to test" and "need to test the case where `Writable` should fail". If this is how *you* test (i.e. modify valid source code to better suite your test cases), then I pitty the next dev after you. No offense intended.

Comment: my bad, didn't understand question properly, have u tried a ridiculously long name(1000 - 2000 characters),

Comment: If you change your answer, that did it. Most FS have a file name size limit of 255 or 260 characters. I supplied a 300 characters file name and the test passes.